# Identifying which TapGestureRecognizer was tapped in XCode / Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode6, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to do a simple thing: I set up two rectangular views on main storyboard and then include both with TapGestureRecognizers. I then link these TGR's to a single @IBAction function. Now I need somehow to id which one of the TGR's was tapped.

```
@IBAction func tapOneAct(sender: AnyObject) {
    println(sender)
}
```

It tried using tags but could not make it work, apparently TGR's can't be tagged? println(sender) tells me that the system is working but I need something that I can use for further coding, like tag or other value.

Thx for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `Restoration ID` of view from `Identity Inspector` of storyboard and then your function will look like :

```
func tapOneAct(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if(sender.view!.restorationIdentifier == "view1") // view1 is `Restoration ID` of 1st view
    {
        println("View1 is tapped!")
    }
    if(sender.view!.restorationIdentifier == "view2")// view2 is `Restoration ID` of 2nd view
    {
        println("View2 is tapped!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly! Only change is that my Xcode wants to use (sender.view!?.restoration...) instead of (sender.view!.restoration...)

Answer (score 7):

By using `tag` property you can do it this way:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tapGestureView1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapOneAct:")
        let tapGestureView2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapOneAct:")
        //add gesture into both Views.
        view1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureView1)
        view2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureView2)

    }

    func tapOneAct(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){

        if let tag = sender.view?.tag {
            switch tag {
            case 1:
                println("First View Tapped")
            case 2:
                println("Second View Tapped")
            default:
                println("Nothing Tapped")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer the 1st method, I used tags in a previous project and in it they worked fine, thought it would be just as easy with TGR's.